# Sorting Floating Point Values

Tags: algorithm, c, sorting, floating-point

I found sorting large arrays by a comparator that looks at the floating-point difference problematic, especially `-ffast-math`, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442725/is-floating-point-addition-commutative-in-c.) This is intended to compare 32-bit floats exactly using integer arithmetic. Most references cited concern themselves with radix sort:

- Nicholas Chapman, https://www.forwardscattering.org/post/34;
- Michael Herf, http://stereopsis.com/radix.html;
- Pierre Terdiman, http://codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm;
- https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/radix-sort-on-floating-point-numbers/;
- https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/.

Using a comparison sort, like `qsort`, it only has to decide on a total order of IEEE-754 numbers by comparing two at a time.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_SUCCESS qsort */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */
#include <time.h>   /* clock */
#include <limits.h> /* INT_MAX */
#include <math.h>   /* C99 floating point macros */
#include <stdint.h> /* C99 uint32_t */

struct Foo { float x; };

/** Compares float {x} values of {Foo} exactly. Assumes IEEE-754-ish 32-bit
 float has the same endianness as {uint32_t}. References:
 \cite{KimYoonKim2011FastSortFloatingPoint},
 Nicholas Chapman \url{ https://www.forwardscattering.org/post/34 },
 Michael Herf \url{ http://stereopsis.com/radix.html },
 Pierre Terdiman \url{ http://codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm },
 \url{ https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/radix-sort-on-floating-point-numbers/ },
 \url{ https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/ },
 \url{ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632237/any-c-compiler-where-evaluates-to-larger-than-one }.
 @implements <Foo>Comparator
 @return Greater than, equal to, or less than 0, if the {Foo.x} pointed to by
 {av} is greater than, equal to, or less than the {Foo.x} pointed to by {bv}. */
static int x_cmp(const void *av, const void *bv) {
    const struct Foo *const a = av, *const b = bv;
    union { float f; uint32_t u; } ax, bx;
    ax.f = a->x, bx.f = b->x;
    {
        /* @chux unsigned -> uint32_t critical fix */
        const uint32_t ax_abs = ax.u & 0x7fffffff, ax_sign = ax.u & 0x80000000;
        const uint32_t bx_abs = bx.u & 0x7fffffff, bx_sign = bx.u & 0x80000000;
        const uint32_t same = !(ax_sign ^ bx_sign);
        /* if(!same) return ax_sign^1; else return ax_sign^(ax_abs - bx_abs); */
        return ax_sign ^ (!same + same * (ax_abs - bx_abs));
    }
}

/** Tests {x_cmp}. */
int main(void) {
    struct Foo foos[32]; /* could be bigger */
    const size_t foos_size = sizeof foos / sizeof *foos;
    unsigned i;
    union { float f; uint32_t u; } x;

    assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
    srand((unsigned)clock()), rand();
    foos[0].x = 0.0f;
    foos[1].x = 0.0f;
    foos[2].x = -0.0f;
    foos[3].x = INFINITY; /* C99 */
    foos[4].x = -INFINITY; /* C99 */
    foos[5].x = NAN; /* C99 */
    foos[6].x = (x.u = 0x807fffff, x.f); /* subnormal */
    foos[7].x = (x.u = 1, x.f); /* subnormal */
    for(i = 8; i < 2 * foos_size / 3; i++) {
        foos[i].x = rand() / (0.5f * RAND_MAX / INT_MAX) - INT_MAX;
    } for( ; i < foos_size; i++) {
        foos[i].x = rand() / (0.5f * RAND_MAX / 100.0f) - 100.0f;
    }
    qsort(foos, foos_size, sizeof foos[0], &x_cmp);
    for(i = 1; i < foos_size; i++) {
        printf("%g <= %g\n", foos[i - 1].x, foos[i].x);
        /* isnan C99 */
        assert(isnan(foos[i - 1].x) || isnan(foos[i].x)
            || foos[i - 1].x <= foos[i].x);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compiled it on GCC 4.2.1 MacOS, GCC 5.4.0 Linux, and MSVC15, (the order of the NaN macro switched, thus `isnan`,) I think it's valid? Could the comparator be done in less steps?

---

Edit:

`int32_t`: increasing injection mod the branch cut.
[image: int32_t]

IEEE 754-ish `float`: (one way) to get rid of the singularity and make it monotonic is to invert the negative values and flip the sign bit on positive values, [Radix Sort, Sorting a float data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640906/radix-sort-sorting-a-float-data).

[image: IEEE 754 floating point.]

Comment: You shouldn't rely on internal FP representation like that, it won't work properly with every target CPU/FPU.

Comment: Hmmmm: Idea: If `x_cmp()` only did `uint32_t *a = av; uint32_t *b = bv; return (*a > *b ) - (*a < *b);`, then the array would be quickly  "sorted" per its binary image.  Assuming a matching `float/int32_t`.endian and binary32 FP, a post analysis could fold, in O(n) time, the resultant array as needed.  I suspect it would be faster.  Perhaps I'll try it later.

Comment: If you care about performance, don't use `qsort`. Here is [an old post](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/comparison-of-internal-sorting-algorithms/) on the performance of sorting. `qsort` was very slow. I don't know how much it stands nowadays, but calling function pointers that frequently hurts anyway. In addition, `qsort` is badly designed. Generic sorting algorithms can implemented with a single "less than" operator (like in C++ STL). You don't need any arithmetic operations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think I'm relying on: (1) float is 32 bits (I check this with an assert,) (2) negative sign bit is 31, (3) ~`int32_t(float)++` is 1 ULP bigger. Specifically, this applies to IBM floats as well. The answer by @chux made no such assumption. @user172818 true; I assume this applies to all comparison sorts, on average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `ax_sign ^ (!same + same * (ax_abs - bx_abs));` returns the incorrect signed result if `int` is not 32-bit.  Certainly a problem if `int` is 16-bit and likely if `int` is 64-bit.  If `unsigned/int` needs to be 32-bit, use `(u)int32_t`
2. `,` operator reduces clarity here.  Suggest 2 lines of code

   ```
   // ax.f = a->x, bx.f = b->x;
   ax.f = a->x;
   bx.f = b->x;
   ```
3. I ran test cases and found OP's `x_cmp()` functionally correct for finite float over a 2,000,000,000 test cases.
4. As a test case, I tried OP's original `x_cmp()` versus the below and was at least 10% faster with the new code.  Of course, that is just one platform comparison, yet aside from NaN issues, the below code is functionally similar to OP's and as a plus, is highly portable - unlike OP's.  The point being that OP's compare method needs some reference point to justify the bit magic.

   ```
   static int x_cmp_ref(const void *av, const void *bv) {
     return (*(float*)av > *(float*)bv) - (*(float*)av < *(float*)bv);
   }
   ```
5. OP's has not stated the compare functionality of Not-a-number `float`s. A desirable aspect is that all NaN sort to one side, either all greater or all less than any other number, regardless of the NaN's "sign".  `x_cmp()` considers sign first without regard to NaN-ness.

---

As a reference, I used the following to generate random `float`

```
float randf() {
  union {
      float f;
      unsigned char uc[sizeof (float)];
  } u;
  do {
    for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof u.uc; i++) {
      u.uc[i] = (unsigned char) rand();
    }
  } while (!isfinite(u.f));
  return u.f;
}
```

---

At a later time, I may try to implement the idea in [this comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161154/sorting-floating-point-values/161158#comment305493_161154)

Comment: 1. Good catch, it should be all uint32_t to match float; 2. thanks; 4. that would be great! but it didn't work for negative values; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640906/radix-sort-sorting-a-float-data; 5. I agree that it's arguably best to keep them all NaNs one place; otoh, why change arbitrarily no-work placement without good reason?

Comment: @NeilEdelman Thanks for your thoughts.  #4 returns the correct `int` when comparing `float` of which 1 or both are negative. Unclear on "it didn't work for negative values" as it applies to `qsort()` used here.  #5 There is a good reason: A typical application for a list with NaNs is to sort them out to the end, that way a simple reduction in `N` can lop them off the array.  As I see it, a robust compare concenring NaN can be done with low cost.  Yet as you imply, NaN handling is not universal.

Comment: I was reinterpreting them as `uint32_t`, which did not sort the negative values correctly; leaving them as `floats` produced the right output. I measure it to be 25% faster on my machine. I did a sequence of values that differed by 1 ulp, and it appears to be stable, and looks cool.

Comment: *As you said, the placement of NaNs in a comparison sort with `float` is different than `int32_t`; comparisons with `float` NaNs are not treated as equivalence relations.